# CSS - Select a next element

Tags: html, css, selector

I don't know how to explain this very well but...
I want to select an element but it's like "far" from other one

Like this:

```
<div class="image-div">
    <img src="forest.png" class="image forest">
</div>
<p>
    I want to change the color of this text if the image there ^ is "forest", which I'll change with JS
</p>

.image.forest [some selector idk] p {
    color: red;
}
.image.train [some selector idk] p {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: "which I'll change with JS" since you are already using JS, why not use it to also apply a class to `p` - then you can have css like `img.forest {} ... p.forest{}`

Comment: I didn't think on this lol

Answer (score 2):

You could re-write it like this if it works for you.

```
<div class="image-div forest">
    <img src="forest.png" class="image">
</div>

<p>I want to change the color of this text if the image there ^ is "forest", which I'll change with JS</p>

<style>
  .forest + p {
    color: red;
  }
  .train + p {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to go from `<img>` to `<div>` to `<p>`, but going from `<img>` to `<div>` presents a problem: there is no CSS selector that allows one to reference an element that is higher up in the DOM tree, i.e. no child-to-parent selector.

Instead, you can apply the `.forest` class to the `<div>`.

HTML:

```
<div class="image-div forest">
    <img src="forest.png" class="image">
</div>
<p>
    I want to change the color of this text if the image there ^ is "forest", which I'll change with JS
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.forest + p {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a parent.

Comment: OP doesn't seem to be asking how to achieve a parent selector.

Comment: I've clarified.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just add a class to the p tag right after the forest image.

```
<div class="image-div">
    <img src="forest.png" class="image forest">
</div>
<p class="forest-paragraph"></p>

.forest-paragraph {
     color: #000;
}
```

Comment: The class may change, any <p> tag after `.forest` should reflect the style, he may have other images wrapped in a <div> with other classes ie `.desert` or `.sea`